# Why java System.out.print method have various forms?

Tags: java

```
public void print(long l) {
    write(String.valueOf(l));
}

/**
 * Prints a floating-point number.  The string produced by <code>{@link
 * java.lang.String#valueOf(float)}</code> is translated into bytes
 * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
 * are written in exactly the manner of the
 * <code>{@link #write(int)}</code> method.
 *
 * @param      f   The <code>float</code> to be printed
 * @see        java.lang.Float#toString(float)
 */
public void print(float f) {
    write(String.valueOf(f));
}

/**
 * Prints a double-precision floating-point number.  The string produced by
 * <code>{@link java.lang.String#valueOf(double)}</code> is translated into
 * bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
 * bytes are written in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link
 * #write(int)}</code> method.
 *
 * @param      d   The <code>double</code> to be printed
 * @see        java.lang.Double#toString(double)
 */
public void print(double d) {
    write(String.valueOf(d));
}

/**
 * Prints an array of characters.  The characters are converted into bytes
 * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
 * are written in exactly the manner of the
 * <code>{@link #write(int)}</code> method.
 *
 * @param      s   The array of chars to be printed
 *
 * @throws  NullPointerException  If <code>s</code> is <code>null</code>
 */
public void print(char s[]) {
    write(s);
}
```

[Source code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEUVX.png)

I opened java.io.PrintStream class file. And i found there are various print methods. Each method 99% same without only parameter type. Many programming guide books suggest that you can use generic(or template) in this situation. So i'm wondering why java.io.Printstream do not use generic.

Comment: Primitive types aren't objects, so they can't be used as generic types. Also some methods do have specific behaviour for a particular type. _Also_ these methods predate the existence of generics in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use a method with

```
public <T> void print(T value);
```

and you would want to print an `int` value then if would be used as

```
public void print(Integer value);
```

so the `int` value would be boxed what means lost in performance and unnecessary memory usage.

That is the reason that you will often find method overloads for all primitiv data-types

---

Also as Taschi pointed out, the class is simply older than generics in Java.

Comment: Automatic boxing / unboxing and generics did not even exist in Java 1.0.